# rails simple_form collection use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have problem.

I want to my posts/new.html.erb join dropdown.

I have two model post and category.

I hope when new post can choose my category.

posts/new.html.erb/

`<%= simple_form_for @post do |f|%>
      <%= f.input :category_id, as: :select %>
    <% end %>`

helper/posts.helper.rb

`def collect_category
      @cat_arr = []
      Category.all.each do |cat|
        @cat_arr = cat
      end
      return @cat_arr
    end`

I can't understand simple_form collection

Please help me, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your Post model, make sure you have:

```
belongs_to :category, class_name: "Category"
```

And your Category model, put:

```
has_many :posts, class_name: "Post"
```

Now on your form, you can do:

```
<%= f.association :category, as: :select %>
```

Optional: collection: Category.all(order: 'name') or whatever you want to display it by and order if you want.

You'll probably have to add attr_accessor for category_id on your Post model as well.

Comment: I try it. But have a problem

RuntimeError in Posts
`
<%= f.association :category_id, collection: Category.all, as: :select%>
`

Comment: Because view(new.html.erb) use<%= post.category.name %> can't find

It not set value(choose value) to my data(Post.new.category_id).

Comment: You can do category.posts , since posts belongs to category... Do rails console and inspect if they're being created..

Comment: thants a lot. I find problem. I forgot strong parmater. XD